# How do I convert pyo3 PyComplex back into PyObject in rust

Tags: rust, pyo3

I'm using pyo3 to try and make python functions run in rust

I am trying to make a function which takes in two PyAny objects and gets a f64 value out of them and uses those to initialize a PyComplex object and then return it as a PyResult. The `.into_py()` is giving me a strange error

```
the trait bound `&PyComplex: pyo3::IntoPy<PyObject>` is not satisfied
the trait `pyo3::IntoPy<Py<PyComplex>>` is implemented for `&PyComplex`
for that trait implementation, expected `Py<PyComplex>`, found `PyObject`
```

My function is the following:

```
#[pyfunction]
fn imaginary(a: &PyAny, b: &PyAny) -> PyResult<PyObject> {
    let gil: GILGuard = Python::acquire_gil();
    let py: Python<'_> = gil.python();
    let real: f64 = a.extract()?;
    let imag: f64 = b.extract()?;
    let d: PyObject = PyComplex::from_doubles(py, real, imag).into_py(py);
    Ok(d)
}
```

Please excuse the sloppy code, I'm only just learning how to use pyo3 and pointers are appreciated

I tried the compilers suggestion which was to use this line

```
let d: PyObject = <&PyComplex as pyo3::IntoPy<T>>::into_py(PyComplex::from_doubles(py, real, imag), py)?;
```

instead of the other `let d:` line I had, but it didn't work because T isn't defined in the scope. I tried adding T to the function signature but that didn't work because python functions cant take a rust type parameter.

I also tried replacing T with PyComplex or &PyComplex hoping that would work but no luck.

What can I do to get this working?

Comment: Why are you doing this conversion in the first place? You can just take `Python<'py>` parameter and return `&'py PyComplex`.

Comment: Sorry can you explain that a bit more? I'm not sure I understand what you mean, I was under the understanding that I should convert everything into a PyObject before wrapping it in ```Ok()```?

Comment: No you are not. PyO3 handles any type perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this conversion is by [calling `to_object`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/conversion/trait.ToPyObject.html#required-methods) method.

```
use pyo3::{prelude::*, types::PyComplex};


#[pyfunction]
fn imaginary(py: Python<'_>, a: &PyAny, b: &PyAny) -> PyResult<PyObject> {
    let real: f64 = a.extract()?;
    let imag: f64 = b.extract()?;
    let d: PyObject = PyComplex::from_doubles(py, real, imag).to_object(py);
    Ok(d)
}

/// A Python module implemented in Rust.
#[pymodule]
fn complex_python(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(imaginary, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Now you can import this into your python interpretter.

```
>>> import complex_python
>>> 
>>> complex = complex_python.imaginary(1, 2)
>>> complex
(1+2j)
>>> type(_)
<class 'complex'>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to find